# How can I pass input and get output form my Tensorflow Lite model in android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

When I add a tensorflow lite model to my android app.
It suggests a auto generated code.

```
val model = Model.newInstance(context)

// Creates inputs for reference.
val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 50), DataType.FLOAT32)
inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer

// Releases model resources if no longer used.
model.close()
```

Now lets assume my input shape in python is a int array of 50 number [1,2,3...]
and it gives an output of float value.

In what ways I have to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll use bytebuffer to store input in little endian format (as tflite works in this format only).
Replace (1 x 4) with 50 x 4 and for input use a loop of len 50 to add data. Similarly , manipulate output using loop.

Sample code:

```
                EditText inputEditText;

                inputEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberDecimal);
                Float data= Float.valueOf(inputEditText.getText().toString());
                ByteBuffer byteBuffer= ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1*4);
                byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // ensure little endian
                byteBuffer.putFloat(data);

                Model1 model = Model1.newInstance(getApplicationContext());

                // Creates inputs for reference.
                TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 1}, DataType.FLOAT32);
                inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

                // Runs model inference and gets result.
                Model1.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
                TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

                // Releases model resources if no longer used.
                TextView tv= findViewById(R.id.textView);
                float[] data1=outputFeature0.getFloatArray();

                tv.setText(outputFeature0.getDataType().toString());
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(data1[0]));


                model.close();
```